# making dynamically generated menus in Pyramid

Tags: security, menu, permissions, acl, pyramid

I'm trying to have my menus automatically change according to settings in my code so I don't have logic duplicated in my templates.  Right now I use the route names to generate the urls with `request.route_path(name)` and determine what the current page the user is on with `request.matched_route.name`.  My problem now is that I want to have different permissions on different views and automatically hide menu items that the user doesn't have permission to.

One of the major difficulties is that you can have multiple views for one route.  But even if there's only one view associated with a route, I can't seem to find any simple way to retrieve it.

I'm using URL Dispatch.  Is this something that'd only be do-able with traversal?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use a combination of the following patterns for this:

- My views are organized into classed
- The base class has a basic `_menu` which is a list of `(menu_title, route_name, params)` where `params` is an optionally present dict. When in the template I can use a `menu` property that builds the menu from the request and the above attribute.
- In the template create a function that iterates over theses entries, shows each but checks with something like `has_permission` if the view is actually allowed.

These ideas should get you started on a dynamic solution. It works fine for me, but it might require some more tweaking, for example, I attach another value "active" to the generated menu based on the current route.